# Xcode Static Library Template... build doesn't contain headers?

Tags: iphone, xcode, static

So I'm using the Static Library template included in Xcode. Right now just trying to build a simple template to see how static libraries really work.

Anyways in my static library I have two classes:
mylibrary (.h/.m) - This is simply an NSObject
modalView (.h/.m) - This is a UIViewController

The problem though is when I build the static library. The project builds the mylibrary.a file... however there is no "Headers" folder in the output. This means that when I add the library to my other project it gives "undefined" errors because it can't find the .h file for myLibrary.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drag .h files to the new project, along with .a file

Comment: Hmm I see other frameworks with the .h files in the headers folder under the framework but maybe this is different. Do you just drag the .h files wherever you want?

Comment: @Msencenb we usually keep the implementation files in the libraries

Comment: So dragging in the .h files into the project worked. But only for the device and not the simulator. Do static libraries only work on devices? Also by implementation files you mean the .m files correct?

Comment: @Msencenb Yes .m files, and it should work for both the simulator and the device.

Comment: Static libraries work on both the simulators and devices. You drag both the compile static library file and the .h header files into your project. Also check that they are included in your targets. The main advantage of building and using a framework over a static library (IMHO) is that it uses a standardised directory structure and is easier to manage. One final thing to consider is versioning. The way I do it is to create directories with version numbers. Works just fine, but you have to check your library search paths when updating to ensure they don't still include old version directories.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bunch of scripts here:

https://github.com/drekka/dUsefulStuff/tree/master/scripts

Which I use to build static libraries and frameworks. You might find them useful in helping to assemble your library. The main (controller) build script is here

https://github.com/drekka/dUsefulStuff/blob/master/build.sh